# How I can send JSON on Django request to create a new User and Profile?

Tags: python, json, django, rest, django-rest-framework

From django rest framework site examples I write my UserSerializer.py and my ProfileSerializer is like that:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['facebook_id', 'facebook_token', 'push_device_token', 'photo', 'status', 'level']

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'profile')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Profile.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)
        return user
```

And I'am sending JSON request like this:

```
{
   "username":"admin",
   "email":"e@e.com",
   "password":12345678,
   "profile":{
      "status":1,
      "level":1,
      "facebook_id":1,
      "facebook_token":1,
      "push_device_token":1,
      "photo":"url.com"
   }
}
```

But I only get the error:

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `profile` on serializer `UserSerializer`.
>
> The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `User` instance.
>
> Original exception text was: 'User' object has no attribute 'profile'.

Comment: I expect you shouldn't have profile in the fields list, since it isn't really a field on the model.

Comment: did you try printing validated_data ... also put the full traceback

Comment: @DanielRoseman without profile in the fields list, I get the following error: `The field 'profile' was declared on serializer UserSerializer, but has not been included in the 'fields' option.`

Comment: Show the `ProfileSerializer` please.

Comment: try removing it from fields and as well as declaration profile = ProfileSerializer(). It should work as there is no other dependence b/w two models in serializer.

Comment: @AndreyShipilov I update the question description with ProfileSerializer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could be the lack of reference to the User model. Let's say your Profile model looks like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

The model User will have a `profile_set` attribute and not `profile`. To adjust this use the [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects):

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
```

Comment: When in reality it should be `user = models.OneToOneField(User)`. In which case this problem wouldn't happen.